# Query to select that records from the table having particular column value

Tags: sql, oracle

[image][Ques description]I am having table of bills ,in this I don't want to show the records which is having Doctyp='BIL'

```
BILNO        DOCTYP

1812B00001      BIL 
1812B00001      RCR 
ADVN            CN 
ADVN            DA 
ADVN            RCD 
ADVN            RCR 
ADVN            TF 
AL1707B00006    BIL 
AL1707B00006    RCR
```

I want my output like

```
BILNO   DOCTYP

ADVN    CN 
ADVN    DA 
ADVN    RCD 
ADVN    RCR 
ADVN    TF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` is one option:

```
SQL> with test (bilno, doctyp) as
  2    (select 182, 'bil' from dual union all
  3     select 182, 'xxy' from dual union all
  4     select 111, 'abc' from dual union all
  5     select 111, 'zdv' from dual union all
  6     select 223, 'bil' from dual union all
  7     select 555, 'xzy' from dual
  8    )
  9  select *
 10  from test t
 11  where bilno not in (select bilno
 12                      from test
 13                      where doctyp = 'bil');

     BILNO DOC
---------- ---
       111 zdv
       111 abc
       555 xzy
```

Another is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SQL> with test (bilno, doctyp) as
  2    (select 182, 'bil' from dual union all
  3     select 182, 'xxy' from dual union all
  4     select 111, 'abc' from dual union all
  5     select 111, 'zdv' from dual union all
  6     select 223, 'bil' from dual union all
  7     select 555, 'xzy' from dual
  8    )
  9  select *
 10  from test t
 11  where not exists (select null
 12                    from test t1
 13                    where t1.bilno = t.bilno
 14                      and t1.doctyp = 'bil'
 15                   );

     BILNO DOC
---------- ---
       111 zdv
       111 abc
       555 xzy
```

Comment: @Littlefoot....There are many records. How I'm supposed to add each like :select 182, 'bil' from dual union all

Comment: Lines #1 - 8 represent sample data; you wouldn't be needing this. Query you do need begins at line #9.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.